# Указать папку с сайтом, как корневую директорию

Tags: php

Изначально скрипт стоял на локалхосте, перенесла на хостинг, в папку, то есть скрипт лежит тут  http://site/folder/, а ссылки и роутинг настроены на корневую директорию/. Пыталась поиграться с httaccess, но результатов нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу решить эту проблему?

Код index.php

```
define('ROOT', realpath(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

define('DISPLAY_ERROR', true);

if (DISPLAY_ERROR === true) {
    if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    }
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
} else {
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
   error_reporting(0);
}

require_once ROOT . 'init/bootstrap.php';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте один из вариантов:

```
'/init/bootstrap.php'  

'./init/bootstrap.php'

'../init/bootstrap.php'
```